# Quicktabs and views to create tabbed views

Tags: views, blocks

I see that quicktabs uses blocks as tabs.  This is fine if i create 4 views blocks for 4 single items of a content type and then add them to quick tabs manually.

Is there a workaround to show the latest 4 items of a certain content type using quick tabs and views?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Is this not just a matter of editing the view block to show four items rather than one? Under "Pager" in the view, select "Display a specified number of items" and then the quantity you prefer.

Comment: yep, the problem I was having was an error with quick tabs and the view but it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

for the specific content type, add a filter : specific content type nd sort by date decreased nd limite the number of resulets by pager, nd use offser if you want too.